# CRUD Laravel Botón Actualizar

Tags: php, javascript, css, laravel, crud

Estoy creando una web de un concesionario. Tengo varias vistas en la web y una tabla en una base de datos para enlazar los coches disponibles con la página web. Los campos de la base de datos "vehiculos" son: 'modelo', 'año', 'color', 'motor', 'velocidad' y 'cantidad'.
Mi idea es poner un botón "comprar vehículo" en una vista para que cuando el cliente lo pulse se reste una unidad al campo "cantidad" de la tabla "vehiculos" de la base de datos, simulando que el cliente ha adquirido un vehículo y por lo tanto queda una unidad menos disponible en la base de datos para otro usuario.

¿Me podrías ayudar a hacer este crud con un botón para hacer el update en la base de datos? Llevo varios dias machacando el código e investigando pero en todos los sitios lo veo programado de distinta forma (sin botón para actualizar un dato en la base de datos) y no lo consigo adaptar a mi código.

Mi vista es esta:

```
@extends('plantilla')

<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Wheelstone - Catalogo</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Plantilla-JQuery-(3.4.1).js"> </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              function fMustang(){
                     var divMustang= document.getElementById("informacionMustang");
                     divMustang.style.visibility= "visible";
              }
              function fChevrolet(){
                     var divChevrolet= document.getElementById("informacionChevrolet");
                     divChevrolet.style.visibility="visible";
              }
              function fHarley(){
                     var divHarley= document.getElementById("informacionHarley");
                     divHarley.style.visibility="visible";
              }
              function fHonda(){
                     var divHonda= document.getElementById("informacionHonda");
                     divHonda.style.visibility="visible";
              }
          function fCompraMustang(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
          }
          </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    @if (Route::has('login'))
      <div class="top-right links">
        @auth
        <li id="logout" class="dropdown">
            <a id="textoUser" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" v-pre>
                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>

            <a id="textoLogout" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
            <ul id="fondoOscuro" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                        &nbsp &nbsp Logout

                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </a>
        </li>
        @endauth
      </div>
    @endif

      <div id="contenedor">
      <header>
        <a href="http://localhost/wheelstoneProject/public/">
        <img src="{{asset('img/Logotipo.png')}}" id="imagenLogo"> </a>
        <nav id="fondoHeader">
          <p id="parrafoHeader">
            <a id="enlaces" href="inicio"> Inicio </a>
            &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
            <a id="enlaces" href="catalogo"> Catálogo </a>
            &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
            <a id="enlaces" href="contacto"> Contacto </a>
            &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
            <a id="enlaces" href="iniciarSesion"> Iniciar sesión </a>
          </p>
        </nav>
      </header>
        <article id="formularioTopLeft">
            <section>
                <img onmouseover="fMustang()" src="{{asset('img/FordMustang.jpg')}}" id="FordMustang">
                <p id="informacionMustang">
                Marca: Ford <br/>
                Modelo: Mustang GT 390 <br/>
                Año: 1968 <br/>
                Color: Verde <br/>
                Motor: V8 390 de 4.5L <br/>
                Velocidad máxima: 193km/h <br/>
                <input type="submit" onclick="fCompraMustang()" value="Comprar" name="botonMustang" id="botonComprarMustang">
                </p>
            </section>
        </article>
        <article id="formularioTopRight">
            <section>
                <img onmouseover="fChevrolet()" src="{{asset('img/ChevroletCorvette.jpg')}}" id="ChevroletCorvette">
                <p id="informacionChevrolet">
                Marca: Chevrolet <br/>
                Modelo: Corvette C4 <br/>
                Año: 1983 <br/>
                Color: Rojo <br/>
                Motor: V8 L83 de 5.7L <br/>
                Velocidad máxima: 225km/h <br/>
                <input type="button" onclick="fCompraChevrolet()" value="Comprar" name="botonChevrolet" id="botonComprarChevrolet">
                </p>
            </section>
        </article>
        <article id="formularioBottomLeft">
            <section>
                <img onmouseover="fHarley()" src="{{asset('img/HarleyDavidson.jpg')}}" id="HarleyDavidson">
                <p id="informacionHarley">
                Marca: Harley Davidson <br/>
                Modelo: 2020 Forty Eight <br/>
                Año: 2018 <br/>
                Color: Granate y negra <br/>
                Motor: Evolution de 5.1L <br/>
                Velocidad máxima: 170km/h <br/>
                <input type="button" onclick="fCompraHarley()" value="Comprar" name="botonHarley" id="botonComprarHarley">
                </p>
            </section>
        </article>
        <article id="formularioBottomRight">
            <section>
                <img onmouseover="fHonda()" src="{{asset('img/HondaCBR.jpg')}}" id="HondaCBR">
                <p id="informacionHonda">
                Marca: Honda <br/>
                Modelo: CBR 1000 F <br/>
                Año: 1986 <br/>
                Color: Rojo, blanco y azul <br/>
                Motor: 4 cilindros en línea de 3.8L <br/>
                Velocidad máxima: 260 km/h <br/>
                <input type="button" onclick="fCompraHonda()" value="Comprar" name="botonHonda" id="botonComprarHonda">
                </p>
            </section>
        </article>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Y mi controlador es este:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

    public function webPrincipal(){
      return view('webPrincipal');
    }

    public function inicio(){
      return view('inicio');
    }

    public function catalogo(){
        if(Auth::check()){
          return view ('catalogo');
        } else {
          echo "*Acceso restringido: No tienes permiso para acceder a
          esta sección. Si quieres ver nuestro catálogo y comprar nuestros
          vehículos tienes que iniciar sesión con una cuenta existente.";
          return view('inicio');
        }
    }

    public function contacto(){
      return view('contacto');
    }

    public function iniciarSesion(){
      return view('iniciarSesion');
    }

    public function listadoUsuarios(){
      $user= Auth::user();
      if(Auth::check() && $user->esAdmin()){
        $users= App\User::all();
        return view('listadoUsuarios', compact('users'));
      } else {
        echo "*Acceso restringido: No tienes permiso para acceder a
        esta sección. Si quieres visualizar el listado de usuarios registrados
        tienes que iniciar sesión con la cuenta del administrador.";
        return view('inicio');
      }
    }

    public function listadoVehiculos(){
      $user= Auth::user();
      if(Auth::check() && $user->esAdmin()){
        $vehiculos= App\Vehiculo::all();
        return view('listadoVehiculos', compact('vehiculos'));
      } else {
        echo "*Acceso restringido: No tienes permiso para acceder a
        esta sección. Si quieres visualizar el listado completo de vehículos
        tienes que iniciar sesión con la cuenta del administrador*.";
        return view('inicio');
      }
    }

    public function update(Vehiculo $vehiculo, Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
          'modelo'=>'required',
          'año'=>'required',
          'color'=>'required',
          'motor'=>'required',
          'velocidad'=>'required',
          'cantidad'=>'required',
        ]);
        Vehiculo::find($id)->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('catalogo.blade.php')->with('success', 'Compra realizada con éxito.');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu método *update*, estás buscando en el modelo *Vehiculo* un *$id*, pero este *$id* no lo estás capturando en ninguna parte. Debieses pasar ese *id* desde el *request*. Siempre y cuando el *id* venga en el *request*, sería algo así:

```
Vehiculo::find($request->id)->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Hola Oscar, acabo de cambiar mi código cambiando esa línea pero sigue igual, ahora mi controlador queda así:

public function update(Vehiculo $vehiculo, Request $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
          (los diferentes campos)
        ]);
        Vehiculo::find($request->id)->update($request->all());
        $vehiculo->cantidad= $vehiculo->cantidad-1;
        $vehiculo->save();
        return redirect()->route('catalogo.blade.php')->with('success', 'Compra realizada con éxito.');
    }
Al pulsar el botón en la web sólo me aparece mi alert, pero no resta una unidad,

Comment: Y la vista queda así: :
          function fCompraMustang(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
              update("1");
          }
          function fCompraChevrolet(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
              update("2");
          }
          function fCompraHarley(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
              update("3");
          }
          function fCompraHonda(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
              update("4");
          }

Comment: ¿En tu controlador estás importando el modelo? ```use App\Vehiculo;```?

Comment: Sí, lo estoy importando pero sigue igual.

Answer (score 0):

Recibes el vehículo en el método update del controlador pero no está referenciado arriba el Model:

```
use App\Vehiculo;
```

Luego, no veo que lo envíes desde la vista, pero si lo recibes bien no necesitas volver a buscarlo dentro del método update, lo único que tienes que hacer es:

```
$vehiculo->cantidad = $vehiculo->cantidad-1;
$vehiculo->save();
```

Y luego la redirección.

Parece que estás intentando evitar el refresco de página, pero fijate que estés enviando correctamente los datos al controlador. Para chequear lo que recibes dentro de update podés hacer:

```
dd($request);
```

o

```
dd($vehiculo);
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Vale, ya he modificado ese App\Vehiculo en lugar de App.
He hecho tus modificaciones pero sigue igual, sólo me muestra el alert, no resta una unidad.
El controlador queda así:
public function update(Vehiculo $vehiculo, Request $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
          (los diferentes campos)
        ]);
        Vehiculo::find($request->id)->update($request->all());
        $vehiculo->cantidad= $vehiculo->cantidad-1;
        $vehiculo->save();
        dd($vehiculo);
        return redirect()->route('catalogo.blade.php')->with('success', 'Compra realizada con éxito.');
    }

Comment: Y la vista queda así:
          function fCompraMustang(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
              update("1");
          }
          function fCompraChevrolet(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
              update("2");
          }
          function fCompraHarley(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
              update("3");
          }
          function fCompraHonda(){
              window.alert("Vehiculo comprado correctamente");
              update("4");
          }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, otro comentario, en tu vista no veo que utilices un form que ejecute una ruta hacia el update del controlador y envíe $vehículo, te pego aquí debajo una adaptación de como sería (sólo para el campo modelo, deberías agregar el resto):

```
<form action="{{ route('vehiculos.update', ['vehiculo' => $vehiculo]) }}" method="post">
            @method('PUT')
            @csrf
            <div class="row justify-content-server">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="modelo">Modelo</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="modelo" id="modelo" value="Mustang">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                <button class="btn btn-dark text-light" type="submit" name="button">Comprar Vehículo</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: O sea, hay 2 formas de actualizar, una es enviar $vehículo desde la vista hacia el controlador y alcanza con restarle 1 a cantidad, pero para que esto funcione deberías haber enviado previamente el vehículo hacia la vista también... y la otra es enviando el $id al update del controlador, hacés el find($id) y restas la cantidad... No veo que envíes ni el vehículo ni el id al controlador.

Comment: Hola Fabian, gracias por responder.
Después de adaptar el código según me has puesto arriba me da un error en el navegador, y me indica esto --> Undefined variable: vehiculo